# Connect to Remote SQL Server Using Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a server running on my VPS which hosts the .com that it runs off of.  Normally I Remote into this VPS and open management studio and do what I need to do.

How can I connect to the database on my webserver from my office using Management Studio.  Can I?

Also, what security concerns are there when doing remote connections?

Comment: Which version of SQL server is this, the methods for allowing remote access differ between 2005 and 2008

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check with your hosting if the sql tcp port is open or firewalled (typically port 1433) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

You will also need to configure the sql server to allow remote connections.http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Comment: Ill give it a try.  Are there (m)any security risks I face by doing this?

Comment: There is a possibility that someone guesses or brute forces your password. Also make sure the SQL server has the latest security updates.